# MySQL Rank Not Matching High Score in Table

Tags: mysql, leaderboard, scoring

While making a game the MySQL call to get the top 10 is as follows:

```
SELECT username, score FROM userinfo ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

This seems to work decently enough, but when paired with a call to get a individual player's rank the numbers may be different if the player has a tied score with other players. The call to get the players rank is as follows:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userinfo ui WHERE (ui.score, ui.username) >= (uo.score, uo.username)) AS rank FROM userinfo uo WHERE username='boddie';
```

Example results from first call:

```
+------------+-------+
| username   | score |
+------------+-------+
| admin      |  4878 |
| test3      |  3456 |
| char       |   785 |
| test2      |   456 |
| test1      |   253 |
| test4      |    78 |
| test7      |     0 |
| boddie     |     0 |
| Lz         |     0 |
| char1      |     0 |
+------------+-------+
```

Example results from second call

```
+------+
| rank |
+------+
|   10 |
+------+
```

As can be seen, the first call ranks the player at number 8 on the list, but the second call puts him at number 10. What changes or what can I do to make these calls give matching results?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You are effectively sorting by score desc AND username desc within that, hence boddie comes lower than Lz and char1

Comment: Yah I am beginning to see the mistake after looking at all the great responses below. There is so many good ones haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need in the first query to :

```
ORDER BY 
   score DESC,
   username DESC
```

This way it will reach at rank 10... this is due to the username comparison in the second query :

`(ui.score, ui.username) >= (uo.score, uo.username)`

Comment: Upvote since we had pretty much the same answer in the same minute, but probably want names in ascending alphabetical order, not descending :)

Comment: @BryPie you can do that by changing the second query

Comment: ended up using this due to simplicity and it worked with what I had quite well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would change your Order by to include username, so that you always get the same order. So it would look like:

```
... ORDER BY score DESC, username ASC ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    uo.username,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM userinfo ui WHERE ui.score>uo.score) AS rank
FROM userinfo uo
WHERE uo.username='boddie'
```

Or if you need to get username, score and ranks:

```
SELECT
    uo.username,
    uo.score,
    (@row := @row + 1) AS rank
FROM userinfo uo
JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) r
ORDER BY uo.score DESC, uo.username ASC
```

You could add

```
HAVING uo.username = 'boddie'
```

to get only one user

Comment: in ur case all users that have score = 0 they will have the same rank :)

Comment: yeah but you need a way do differentiate them , like the OP tried

Comment: Not sure using HAVING for your 2nd answer is safe due to the possible ways that MySQL can chose to optimise queries using user variable

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:-

```
SELECT UsersRank
FROM 
(
    SELECT userinfo.score, userinfo.username, @Rank:=@Rank+1 AS UsersRank
    FROM userinfo 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT (@Rank:=0)) Sub1
    ORDER BY userinfo.score DESC, userinfo.username
) Sub2
WHERE username = 'boddie'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT (COUNT(*)+1) AS rank
FROM   userinfo ui
WHERE  ui.score > (SELECT score
                   FROM   userinfo
                   WHERE  username='boddie');
```